# How to get a list of keys from Cloud Bigtable cbt tool?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable, cbt

I am using `cbt tool` to inspect the data of some tables. I want to know what are the typical fields in the rows of my table. The only way to do this is to use `cbt read`. But `cbt read` select massive amounts of rows, which I don't want to do. I just want to find a few row keys so I can run `cbt lookup <row-key>` with them.

I'm doing this because BigTable is simply an enterprise-class HBase, thus it is a schema-less DB. The only way to find out the columns of the table is to inspect the records.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid massive read amount of rows and select few row keys only, you can use `[start=<row-key>]` and `[end=<row-key>]` or with `count=<n>` to limit the number of rows read, here's the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference#read_rows).

**For example, using `[start=<row-key>]` and `[end=<row-key>]` :**

```
cbt read my-table start=r2 end=r4
```

**output:**

```
----------------------------------------
r2
  cf1:c1                                   @ 2021/08/24-02:34:56.750000
    "test2-value2"
----------------------------------------
r3
  cf1:c1                                   @ 2021/08/24-02:38:36.748000
    "test3-value3"
```

**with `count=<n>`**:

```
cbt read my-table start=r2 end=r4 count=1
```

**output:**

```
----------------------------------------
r2
  cf1:c1                                   @ 2021/08/24-02:34:56.750000
    "test2-value2"
```

Comment: @Calicoder let me know if you have clarification on my answer.

Comment: Well... that works although it kind of defies the "I don't really know what the key is"...